# ajax jquery json, call google geo api - cant catch the answer

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json, asp-classic

i would like to use google geo api
if i past this into the url:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=montreal&sensor=false

i get json object as google api doc says

now, what i want to do is:

do it in ajax so thats my code:

```
$.ajax(
        {
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=montreal&sensor=false',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        //do stuff
                                }
        }
                              )

     };
```

it all work fine,
i just want to show the user loading animation untill i get the object back, sometimes it takes time for that..

any ideas??
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alert()` statement is in the `success` callback function, so the alert definitely doesn't come before you've received the object. However, the object you're getting back doesn't have a `d` property, so calling `alert(data.d)` is going to output `undefined`.